# How to get field value instead of column name?

Tags: android, cursor, android-viewbinder

I want to fill a list with data from a cursor this way:

```
            myCursor = myDBA.getAllCompanies();
    startManagingCursor(myCursor);

    myListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.company_row, myCursor, FROM, TO);

    myListAdapter.setViewBinder(VIEW_BINDER);

    companiesListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

I use a custom `ViewBinder` to fill two `TextViews` and one `ImageView` in each row:

```
private final ViewBinder VIEW_BINDER = new ViewBinder() {
    /**
     * Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the
     * specified view.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        int viewId = view.getId();
        switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.company_name:
        case R.id.company_desc:
            Log.d(TAG, "Binding TextView");
            TextView venueText = (TextView) view;
            venueText.setText(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
            return true;

        case R.id.company_icon:
            Log.d(TAG, "Binding ImageView");
            ImageView venueIcon = (ImageView) view;
            String iconName;

                iconName = cursor.getString(columnIndex); //Here I get the column name not the field value

            Resources resources = myContext.getResources();
            Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(resources
                    .getIdentifier("my.package:drawable/"
                            + iconName, null, null));
            venueIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

My problem is the `cursor.getString()` method call returns the column name not the value of the field and so I get hundreds of rows with column names.

Update:

My `getAllCompanie`s includes a `moveToFirst` call on the `Cursor` but still I get column names:

```
public Cursor getAllCompanies(){
    Cursor s = myDB.query(TABLE, KEYS, WHERE, null, null, null, null);
    s.moveToFirst();
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to move the cursor to the first index `cursor.moveToFirst();` then do `cursor.getString(columnIndex);` ?

There is another way, create one List or array that will hold the values from the cursor, access all the data inside it by iterating through the cursor

```
while(cursor.isAfterLast()==false)
{
  list.add(cursor.getString(thestringcollumnindex);
 cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

then just do

```
iconName=list.get(columnindex);
```

This solution is not the best but how ever serves the purpose.

Comment: I'll second this: call `moveToFirst` in `myDBA.getAllCompanies();` and you should be fine.

Comment: It's not important where he will call moveToFirst, as long as it is before he fetches the data from it, right?

Comment: That's right: it is however easiest to bury it in the function that's returning the `Cursor`. If it returns a `Cursor` it is ready to go: no further fumbling required. If `moveToFirst` fails then return null and skip the entire exercise.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I tried with `moveToFirst`, but I still get column names. I'll try with an array.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
 cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
```

it will get you the string from the column_name