# cursor return column names instead of values

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I want to fetch data from table "student" in SQLite android database

and here is the method that I use to retrieve the data

```
public Cursor getAllStudent(){


    SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] columns={"_id",
            "'reg_number'",
            "'School_id'",
            "'class_id'",
            "'first_name'",
            "'last_name'",
            "'PPN'",
            "'photo'",
            "'CyncStatus'"};

    Cursor cursor=null;

    try {
        cursor = db.query("student",columns,null, null,null,null,null);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("select student failed:  %d", e.toString());
    }


return cursor;


}
```

and this is how I iterate through the result

```
Cursor c1 = studentHelperAdapter.getAllStudent();


c1.moveToFirst();
while (!c1.isAfterLast()){

String reg = c1.getString(1); // return column name not value
String name = c1.getString(4); //return name column  not value
String reg = c1.getString(5); //return name column not value


c1.moveToNext();
} 

c1.close();
```

and I have tried to add this line below to see cursor content and I realized that no data was fetched there are only column names

```
Log.d("AB cursor ",android.database.DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c1));
```

Anyway, there 2 similar questions but none of the solutions solved my problem

[Get the field value with a Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903343/cursor-get-the-field-value-android)

[How to get field value instead of column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769820/how-to-get-field-value-instead-of-column-name)

I look forward to see your answer here, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your column names should just be strings.

```
"reg_number" not "'reg_number'"
```

also make sure that you are using correct types.  Is the value stored in column "reg_number" really a String?